# HibernateTransactionManager : possible to throw exception without rollback?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In Spring, I have declared a method to be transactional. I use HibernateTransactionManager. Now, I would like to throw an exception from this method, but I do not want hibernate to rollback the transaction. Is it possible to specify which exceptions caused the rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring's default rollback behaviour is this:

> [...] the Spring
>   Framework's transaction infrastructure
>   code will, by default, only mark a
>   transaction for rollback in the case
>   of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that
>   is, when the thrown exception is an
>   instance or subclass of
>   RuntimeException. (Errors will also -
>   by default - result in a rollback.)
>   Checked exceptions that are thrown
>   from a transactional method will not
>   result in the transaction being rolled
>   back.

You can override this, though. It depends on what mechanism you've used for demarcating your transactions (e.g. annotations, XML, etc), but the gist of the exception-rollback stuff is in the [spring docs here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back).

For example, if you use the `@Transactional` annotation, then you can specify the `rollbackFor` attribute to the annotation to specify which exceptions cause a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

There are two attributes which you can use to specify which Exception should/shouldn't cause a rollback on `@Transactional` annotations:

Specify which Exceptions shouldn't cause rollback:

```
@Transactional (dontRollbackOn = {NotFoundException.class})
```

Specify which Exception should cause a rollback:

```
@Transactional (rollbackOn = {ForbiddenException.class})
```